# Showing that $ \int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|^4 \: dx $ is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f_k : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{0}^{1} |f_k(x)|^4 \: dx < \infty $ and
$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} |f_k(x) - f(x)| \: dx = 0.$$
Show that $ \int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|^4 \: dx < \infty$.

I found that
$$ \int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|^4 \: dx \leq 2^4 \int_{0}^{1} |f_k(x) - f(x)|^4 \: dx + 2^4 \int_{0}^{1} |f_k(x)|^4 \: dx,$$
and I am not sure how to proceed after this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the concept of uniform integrability?

Comment: No, I think I have seen the definition, but I don't really understand what it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you show there is a subsequence $\{f_{k_j}\}$ of  $\{f_k\}$ that converges pointwise almost everywhere to $f$?

If so, this is a quick application of Fatou's lemma:
$$\int_0^1 |f(x)|^4 \, dx = \int_0^1 \lim_j |f_{k_j}(x)|^4 \, dx \le \liminf_j \int_0^1 |f_{k_j}(x)|^4 \, dx < \infty.$$